# Laravel 9 + Passport not return data with the success (200) response

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-passport

In my company we are developing management software with the php stack (Laravel9 with API) + mysql and Passport for login.
By decision of the development team we are developing and testing the API all in GET.
The project repo has already pre-configured some of the APIs to be developed, and in particular the login ones.
But I have the following problem.
When I call the login GET I get the call status 200, but the response data is not shown.
While if I perform the same call, mistaking the credentials, I correctly get the 401 response with the relative body of the response.

Do you have any suggestions or advice?

mycode:

- api.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthenticatedSessionController;
use Modules\Admin\Http\Controllers\AdminDashboardController;
use Modules\Admin\Http\Controllers\UserController;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::domain('http://api.mysite.test')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return redirect('api/docs');
    });

    Route::group(['prefix' => '/api/admin'], function () {
        Route::get('/login', [AuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'storeAdminAPI']); // THIS IS THE API TESTED
        Route::get('/dashboard', [AdminDashboardController::class, 'dashboardAPI']);
        Route::get('/export/docs', [AdminDashboardController::class, 'getDocumentiAPI']);
        Route::get('/export/users', [AdminDashboardController::class, 'getUsersAPI']);
        Route::get('/export/versamenti', [AdminDashboardController::class, 'getVersamentiAPI']);
        Route::get('/export/user', [AdminDashboardController::class, 'getUserAPI']);
    });

    Route::group(['prefix' => '/api'], function () {
        Route::get('/login', [AuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'storeAPI']);
        Route::get('/dashboard', [UserController::class, 'dashboardAPI']);
    });
});
```

- controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests\Auth\LoginRequest;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Role;
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Permission;
use Spatie\Multitenancy\TenantFinder\TenantFinder;
use Spatie\Multitenancy\Models\Tenant;
use App\Models\AdminUser;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;


class AuthenticatedSessionController extends Controller
{


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
        $this->middleware('guest:admin')->except('logout');
        $this->middleware('guest:web')->except('logout');
    }

    /**
     * Display the login view.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('auth.login');
    }

    public function createAdmin()
    {
        return view('auth.admin.login');
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming authentication request.
     *
     * @param  \App\Http\Requests\Auth\LoginRequest  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function store(LoginRequest $request)
    {
        if (Auth::guard('web')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password], $request->get('remember'))) {
            $user = Auth::guard('web')->user();
            activity()
            ->causedBy($user)
            ->log($user->email.' user login');
            return redirect()->intended(RouteServiceProvider::ADMIN);
        } else {
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['user' => "Incorrect username or password"]);
        }
    }

    public function storeAdmin(LoginRequest $request)
    {

        if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password], $request->get('remember'))) {
            $adminUser = Auth::guard('admin')->user();
            activity()
            ->causedBy($adminUser)
            ->log($adminUser->email.' admin login');
            return redirect()->intended(RouteServiceProvider::ADMIN);
        } else {
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['admin' => "Incorrect username or password"]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Destroy an authenticated session.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function destroy(Request $request)
    {

        $user = auth()->user();

        activity()
        ->causedBy($user)
        ->log($user->username.' logout');

        Auth::guard('web')->logout();



        $request->session()->invalidate();

        $request->session()->regenerateToken();

        return redirect('/login');
    }

    /**
     * Destroy an authenticated session.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function destroyAdmin(Request $request)
    {

        $adminUser= Auth::guard('admin')->user();
        activity()
        ->causedBy($adminUser)
        ->log($adminUser->email.' admin logout');

        Auth::guard('admin')->logout();

        $request->session()->invalidate();

        $request->session()->regenerateToken();

        return redirect('/admin/login');
    }

    public function storeAdminAPI(LoginRequest $request)
    {
        
        if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email' => request('email'), 'password' => request('password')], $request->get('remember'))) {
            $user=Auth::guard('admin')->user();
            // revoke any currently active access tokens
            $userTokens = $user->tokens;
            foreach($userTokens as $token) {
                if ($token->name !== 'API Access Token (Admin)') {
                    continue;
                }
                $token->delete();
            }  
            // create a new access token
            $tokenResult = $user->createToken('API Access Token (Admin)');
            $token = $tokenResult->token;
            
            $token->expires_at = Carbon::now()->addYears(10);
            $token->save();
            
            //Auth::guard('admin')->logout();
            
            return response()->json([
                'status' => "Success",
                'code' => 1,
                'message' => "Token generated successfully",
                'data' => [
                    'email' => $user->email,
                    'access_token' => $tokenResult->accessToken,
                    'token_type' => 'Bearer',
                    'expires_at' => Carbon::parse(
                        $tokenResult->token->expires_at
                    )->toDateTimeString(),
                    'user' => $user
                ],
            ], 200);
        } else {
            return response()->json([
                'status' => "Error",
                'code' => 0,
                "message" => "Unauthorized"
            ], 401);
        }
    }

    public function storeAPI(LoginRequest $request)
    {
        if (Auth::guard('web')->attempt(['email' => request('email'), 'password' => request('password')], $request->get('remember'))) {
            $user= Auth::guard('web')->user();
            
            // revoke any currently active access tokens
            $userTokens = $user->tokens;
            foreach($userTokens as $token) {
                if ($token->name !== 'API Access Token (User)') {
                    continue;
                }
                $token->delete();
            }   

            // create a new access token
            $tokenResult = $user->createToken('API Access Token (User)');
            $token = $tokenResult->token;

            $token->expires_at = Carbon::now()->addYears(10);
            $token->save();

            Auth::guard('web')->logout();

            return response()->json([
                'status' => "Success",
                'code' => 1,
                'message' => "Token generated successfully",
                'data' => [
                    'email' => $user->email,
                    'access_token' => $tokenResult->accessToken,
                    'token_type' => 'Bearer',
                    'expires_at' => Carbon::parse(
                        $tokenResult->token->expires_at
                    )->toDateTimeString(),
                    'user' => $user
                ],
            ], 200);
        } else {
            return response()->json([
                'status' => "Error",
                'code' => 0,
                "message" => "Unauthorized"
            ], 401);
        }
    }
}
```

- user model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable, HasRoles, HasApiTokens;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $table="tbl_utentecensito";
    protected $guard = 'web';
    protected $primaryKey="idUtente";
    protected $fillable = [
        'cognomeNome',
        'email',
        'password',
        'username',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

Comment: If you remove value 'data' from response, do you have anything?

Comment: I've tried to remove 'data' from response but nothing happens...also i've tried to add dump and die into the if and nothing happens too

Comment: Which method are you testing? StoreAPI or storeAdminAPI?

Comment: I'm testing the storeAdminAPI method

Comment: So you should have something like api/api/admin/login as slug, that's right?

Comment: Yes, in my mac i've edited the hosts file, and mapped 127.0.0.1 to api.ct.test, with insomia the url that i call is: `http://api.ct.test:8000/api/admin/login?email=mail@mail.it&password=hello123`

Comment: If it is stored in api.php, then prefix '/api/' is added automatically, so maybe your slug should contain '/api' 2 times and be something like     `http://api.ct.test:8000/api/api/admin/login?email=mail@mail.it&password=hello123`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251233/discussion-between-64bit1990-and-stewiesws).